# How to deal with readFile when file is currently written to

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, io

This might be a bit fuzzy but I have a node app that writes a small counter to a file after doing a bunch of stuff:

```
Fs.readFile( Blender.LOG , function(error, data) { //read the log file
    if( error ) {
        throw error;
    }

    counter = parseInt( data ) + 1; //add this blend

    if(!isNaN( counter )) { //check if the number is a number
        Fs.writeFile( Blender.LOG, counter, function(error) {
            if( error ) {
                throw error;
            }

            Blender.debugging( 'counter: added', 'report' );
        });
    }
    else { //throw error
        Blender.log.error('             Counter number not valid ("' + counter + '"). Leaving it alone for now!');
    }
});
```

Due to high demand on the app I more often than not get a `isNaN` in the callback of the `readFile` because the file is already open for a write from `writeFile` from a previous instance.

*(It is interesting to me that there are no errors thrown though)*

How would you deal with this? I don't really want to make this a blocking write to keep the app fast but I would also like to perhaps queue up the write? I am open for everything though. :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to implemention file counter, for makesure it'is atomic, you need do with this:

```
lock file
read counter from file
increment counter
write counter to file
unlock file
```

Suggest use fs-ext module, if you want to lock a file.

Another way: use redis to store counter, it have atomic increment, and it's performance is better because without need to write to disk frequently.

Comment: Yeah I was investigating redis but am a bit cautious with it's security. An in-memory system that writes to disc only when it has to would be much faster!